Odd behavior in Windows directory permission?
In Linux, I was trying to determine whether a I have read/write permission to a directory, so I did access(dir, R_OK | W_OK) == 0, which worked fine.
I tried to do the same thing in Windows, however, even when I manually remove the read/write permission of myself to a folder, access would still return 0. This doesn't seem like a correct behavior, what is the proper way to determine directory access permission in Windows with C?
Currently, I have to use this:
    bool ok = access(dir, R_OK | W_OK) == 0;
    // in Windows, even if you remove the read/write permission
    // of the user, access would still return 0 (success)!
    DIR* dp = opendir(dir);
    struct dirent* entry = NULL;

    // readdir would return NULL if I don't have permission
    if (dp) entry = readdir(dp);
    return ok && dp && entry;

I tried couple ways to limit myself to a directory.

Firstly, I created another user test under the current PC, and I was trying to access its home folder, granted I am the administrator of my PC, so I thought it would let me access it with UAC (but in my application, I only passed the path, so it never prompted UAC).
Secondly, I then manually remove myself from the access rights of the test user (C:\Users\test) and I was STILL able to call access to it and it reutrn 0
Lastly, even when I add Deny read/write to it, I am STILL able to call access

It is only when I call opendir + readdir that I was able to get a NULL out of the readdir.


When you say "Windows" - what does it mean? MinGW? WSL? Something else?

According to the Windows docs, when used on a directory access only tells you if it exists.

Rather than using the windows API to determine access rights, it may be easier to simply check the readdir return for NULL, and check the last error return via GetLastError() .

@BradLanam perhaps, but I was trying to use the simplest code possible to make it work cross Linux/Windows, and access was doing what it supposed to be doing just fine. I guess I may have to rely on readdir. Stupid Microsoft.

@codenamezero If you want to support unicode filenames, it will become a bit less simple in any case.

The access() function generally should not be used.  In most cases you should just attempt the desired access and handle any failure gracefully.  Because you should do that anyway, as the system state reported on by access() could change by the time you actually attempt to access.

Just use opendir without checking first. If an error occurs, it returns NULL. Check for that instead. If it returns NULL and you want to specifically check if it's permission error, check if errno is EPERM.
This approaches avoids attempting to duplicate the permission checks performed by the OS, and thus avoids any number of pitfalls. It also avoids a race conditions.
